# Let moderators know that custom comment flag will not delete the comment

Tags: feature-request, comments, flags, moderators

Could we let the moderators know with a brief message that when they flag a comment with the `something else` flag that it won't be deleted?

I know that all the current moderators will know, but future moderators may not know or remember the great change to *something else*.

Maybe just a small note, saying that the comment won't be deleted by the moderator action?

Perhaps,

- A link like is done for the Code of Conduct
- Moderator only Ghost text
- Hover Text

[image: Flagging Modal from a Moderator's perspective]

Comment: I agree. Quite a few existing moderators may not be aware of the change, so it's important to let them know.

Comment: What more are you wanting (i.e. please clarify)? All the normal methods of notifying current moderators about this change have already been done. Are you wanting some notification at the time the flag is raised? If a moderator raises such a flag on the site they moderate, then they are going to see the flag in their flag queue. Custom mod flags on comments now work more closely to how custom mod flags on posts work, but not the same. There are no notices for the other idiosyncrasies of how flagging works for moderators. I don't see a lot of benefit of building out something in the UI for this.

Comment: In other words, a moderator already gets the immediate feedback of the comment not being deleted when the flag is raised. They also get the feedback of seeing the flag existing in the mod flag queues/lists. It's just not clear to me what more feedback you would like to see and what additional benefit it will provide.

Comment: They may want to delete the comment and would raise a different flag instead.

Comment: @Makyen If a moderator who routinely used the feature that a comment would be deleted on a custom flag and somehow missed the notice (e.g. because they were inactive at the time the feature was changed), they won't know why their comment wasn't deleted and think it's a bug.

Comment: Back when I was an SE participant in 2013-14, I routinely made grace period edits after someone else commented, and was wondering when I rejoined the site in 2017 why my edit within 5 minutes wasn't combined, until I was told that they made a change in the meantime that comments by others will end the grace period.

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog You mean the moderator missed the notice which is indicated to *every* moderator in the topbar in *every* page of their site and which doesn't go away until they have viewed it? Why would a moderator be using custom moderator flags to delete a comment, when they can just click "delete" for fewer clicks. Your examples appear contrived wrt. this particular issue.

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog A moderator being confused and posting a Meta about it seems to be substantially less impact than asking for developers to make a change to prevent the *possible* future confusion.

Comment: @Makyen To provide a record of why the comment was removed, in case another moderator later stumbles upon the comment and wants to know why, especially in a case where the comment didn't blatantly violate any commenting rules. Also, they won't get the notification if they had previously resigned and were later reinstated after the change.

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog It feels like you're putting up a bunch of straw-man arguments to justify some dev time for something that's not clearly defined (we still have no idea what kind of notice is being asked for) and that has, *at best* a very minimal impact.

Comment: @Makyen As far as I can tell, they're asking for a notification at the time they flag a comment, but yes, the author needs to clarify that. Given that they're a moderator, I believe they've seen the top bar notification, which makes me think so.

Comment: For a new mod - the behaviour would be exactly the same as it would be for a *regular* user.... which means they wouldn't need to give it a second thought..

Comment: Just curious, but why didn't the developers add a hover over or something while they were making these changes?  They were already in there making these changes and could have made a small note for the moderators?  Just curious.  It's not a big deal really, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A couple of thoughts

We rarely instate new mods in a vacuum, and even beta sites often have an experienced mod, and CM team support to show them the ropes.

As for new mods getting confused - the effect of a flag delete is obvious and immediate and the behavior upon custom flagging is *exactly the same* as it would be for a non mod user. As a way to keep notes, previously, if you did a custom flag, and the post was deleted, you could undelete to get the same effect.

As such, I feel like it’s somewhat unlikely that a new mod would get confused by this behaviour.

Comment: What about a moderator who previously made use of the previous configuration (e.g. to leave reasons when deleting comments), who was inactive when the change rolled out and never saw the mod notification, or who resigned before the change and later got reinstated?

Comment: We could roll out a 400 page guide book to all the changes ever.

Comment: More seriously - there's related meta or teams posts + the bright orange modsignal (tm) is just a signpost to them. They could, yanno... catch up on changes when they come in

Comment: Thank you, I think we have covered any concern that might come up.