# Custom comment flags should not auto-delete comments or be automatically marked helpful

Tags: feature-request, bug, flags, moderator-tools, comment-flags

Currently, if a user flags a comment with the "Something else" flag option, and that comment matches the regex to be deleted by a single flag, the comment is immediately deleted and the flag marked helpful, with no moderator ever seeing it.  I believe, but can't immediately verify, that it also counts toward the three-flag auto-deletion, with the same result.

The flag is also marked helpful without a moderator seeing it if the comment is deleted for any reason, including self-deletion by the user, deletion of the question, etc.

This is a problem for several reasons:

- A custom flag may have been requesting an edit, not a deletion.
- A custom flag may have been pointing out some behavior that is not addressed by editing or deleting the comment (we prefer post flags for this, but it's not at all intuitive that people should do this).
- A custom flag may have been pointing out behavior that needs *more* handling, such as more severe misbehavior that should result in a suspension or mod message ([example situation on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427678/208273)).
- A custom flag may request the deletion of multiple comments, such as flags like "All comments up to this point are no longer needed and should be removed."

Basically, **if a user has taken the time to write a flag message for the moderators, a moderator should see that flag message**.  The system should not assume that every custom comment flag is *just* a request to delete the comment.

Comment: Precedent is clear; [we don't do it for custom *post* flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142839), so why do it for custom comment flags? Also, [custom comment flags raised by mods don't auto-delete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360872). The obvious objection to this would be scale, something along the lines of "if the comment can just go away, without anyone else having to look at it, then isn't that going to save everyone time?" Well, if you have two Stack Overflow moderators supporting this, you aren't likely to prevail on the "scale" argument.

Comment: @CodyGray Also, normal users will most of the time save time by just choosing a canned flag option rather than a custom one. Custom ones are few and far between, so no meaningful amount of time will be saved by just making it go away.