# Could we allow for (custom) flagging of our own comments?

Tags: feature-request, comments, flags

While you can flag your own posts (and its sometimes used as a way to get the attention of a moderator), comment flagging on your own comments is disabled. Taking into account that mods can now flag [comments without deletion for attention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360819/135565), and we can deal with people who flag inappropriately as needed. Could users get the ability to self flag our comments?

It may be necessary to draw attention (sparingly) to one's own comment, rather than flagging a question, where the comment might be the heart of the issue that meets mod attention. It also somewhat harmonises the options we have with a comment.

Comment: I cannot think of an example of a comment that I have made and would later wish to flag for the attention of other moderators.  Are you able to include one within your question?

Comment: Well - not just for mods. As a mod, I have other tools. As a regular user, I might want to flag one of my own comments because following comments needed attention, or even as a way to bring mod attention to otherwise unflaggable thing.

Comment: @PolyGeo One example: I post a comment that uses a relative URL, and then the question is migrated, [breaking my link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333880/377214). It would be nicer to flag my own comment itself for moderator attention to have them edit it to use an absolute link for the origin site rather than a broken link on the destination site. Right now, all you can do is flag the post providing a link to your comment and hope that they notice you're referring to your comment.

Comment: Another example: users without enough rep to post comments [can't delete comments that were posted on their behalf](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351079/377214). If the ability for them to do so is not going to be implemented, they should at least be able to flag their own comment and present a case for why it should be deleted.

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog from talking to Stack Overflow moderators, I've gotten the impression that they would rather comments not be flagged for any problem where the requested action is not "please delete this comment" (and suggest a flag on the post instead).  I flag posts all the time with links to vaguely related stuff (e.g., reviews).

Comment: I'm in favor of this too. There are times when I've wanted to clean up comments under a post which includes my own comments (almost always as "no longer needed"), and it feels weirdly asymmetric to delete my own outright while flagging others. It feels like destroying context.